# Integrating Radial Vector Fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coordinate-systems, dipole-moment

Given a integral $$\int_vd^3{r} \;\vec{r}\;\rho(r)$$ and
How do you convert it to spherical coordinate system, noting that $\rho(r)$ is indeed as it is without vector, i.e. it is spherically symmetric $\rho(\vec{r})=\rho(r)$.

$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_o^\pi \dots \rho(r)r^2\sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta dr$$

I guess all I have to do is convert $\vec{r}$ from radial vector coordinate system to spherical coordinate system. But, I am stuck.

**ADDED**
There should not be $v$.
$$\int d^3{r} \;\vec{r}\;\rho(r)$$

Actually, I was asked to calculate dipole moment in this case.

Comment: I think [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86877) I asked on [math.SE] is related.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral of a vector, as you have written it, is just shorthand notation for a vector of integrals.  Concretely, if we write $\vec r= (x,y,z)$ in cartesian coordinates, then
\begin{align}
  \int d^3r\, \vec r\,\rho(r)
&= \left(\int d^3 r\, x\,\rho(r),\int d^3 r\, y\,\rho(r),\int d^3 r\, z\,\rho(r) \right)
\end{align}
Now, we simply note the transformation between cartesian coordinates and spherical coordinates, and use this to evaluate each of these component integrals.  In the convention for $\phi$ and $\theta$ as the polar and azimuthal coordinates respectively, we have
\begin{align}
  x = r\sin\phi\cos\theta, \qquad y = r\sin\phi\sin\theta, \qquad z = r\cos\phi
\end{align}
so we get, for example,
\begin{align}
  \int d^3 r\, x\,\rho(r) = \int dr\,d\phi\,d\theta \,(r^2\sin\phi)(r\sin\phi\cos\theta)\rho(r) 
\end{align}
and similarly for the other components.

Comment: This is all well and good, so +1, but do you think the OP was really supposed to just examine the parity of $\vec{r}$ and $\rho$ over a spherically symmetric domain? Unless I'm mistaken, the answer needs no integration at all, right?

Comment: @ChrisWhite The thought crossed my mind.  What threw me off was the subscript $v$ under the first integral sign in the question which made me think that integration over an arbitrary domain is desired.  Also, there is a lot of talk in the question about converting to spherical coordinates.  Perhaps the OP will clarify re. the domain of integration.

Comment: @ChrisWhite, I have edited. By no integration is needed, do you mean, that it is trivially zero? But how would that be shown mathematically?

Comment: @user59756 Think of what happens to the various objects under the integral sign when you send $\vec r\to -\vec r$.  Alternatively, look at the angular integrations for each component of the integral in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @user59756 Sure thing.